# Spark Data Frames - Check if column is of type integer

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to figure out what data type my column in a spark data frame is and manipulate the column based on that dedeuction.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('MyApp').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv('Path To csv File',inferSchema=True,header=True)

for x in df.columns:
    if type(x) == 'integer':
    print(x+": inside if loop")
```

The  `print(x+": inside if loop")` statement never seems to get executed but I am sure there are several columns that are integer data type.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

You are iterating over the names of your columns so `type(x)` will never equal "integer" (it's always a string).

You need to use [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dtypes`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dtypes)

```
for x, t in df.dtypes:
    if t=="int":
        print("{col} is integer type".format(col=x))
```

It can also be useful to look at the schema using `df.printSchema()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
dict(df.dtypes)['column name'] == 'int'
```

`df.dtypes` returns list of tuples and the easiest way to get the type as string for each column is to convert it to dict.

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
if type(x) == int:
```

type(x) doesn't return 'integers', they should return int for integers.

Comment: You should use `isinstance(x, int)` rather than `type(x) == int`.