# Scala:Checking whether a variable is an integer or not in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am new to scala and wanted to write a udf and method to check whether column in dataframe are integer or not . If its int then corresponding value should be true else false.

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself? Code?

Comment: def checkint(a:String)={
val i="[0-9]*".r
a match{
case i()=>true
case _=>false
}
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Data Frames - Check if column is of type integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49784063/spark-data-frames-check-if-column-is-of-type-integer)

Comment: its in python .. i want in scala

Comment: Done:Create a udf 
val checkint=udf((a:String)=>
{val i="[0-9]*".r
a match{
case i()=>true
case _=>false
}
}
)
and able to get the desired output.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one `udf` which takes `String` as parameter and returns `Boolean` and inside the `udf` directly convert string to integer inside the `Try` block and later check if it is `success` or `failure` like below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import scala.util.Try
import scala.util.Success

val checkIntUDF = udf { (x: String) => val y = Try(x.toInt); y match { case Success(x) => true; case _ => false; } }
```